# Keep Bootstrap-datetimepicker always open also when hitting key enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using  [Eonasdan bootstrap date/timepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker). I want my calendar is always shown, even if I press enter key in the input field. So far I managed showing always open the calendar except when hitting enter key by using attributes:

```
keepOpen: true, 
inline: true, 
debug: true.
```

Segment of JS code

```
$(function () {

            $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
              format: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
              keepOpen: true,
              inline: true,
              debug: true,
              icons:{
                    date: 'fa fa-calendar',
                    up: 'fa fa-chevron-up',
                    down: 'fa fa-chevron-down',
                    previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
                    next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
                    today: 'fa fa-screenshot',
                    clear: 'fa fa-trash',
                    close: 'fa fa-remove'
                }
               //beforeShowDay: 

                    // daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6]



            });
```

Segment of html code:

```
<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker"> 

    <input  id="datepicker" type="text" name="date" class="form-control input-md">

    <div class="input-group-addon dt-cal">

        <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use:

> [keyBinds()](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#keybinds): allows for custom events to fire on keyboard press.

The default value for enter key is:

```
enter: function () {
    this.hide();  // exactly what you don't want...
},
```

It is enough to remove such default behavior:

```
$('#datepicker').data("DateTimePicker").keyBinds({'enter': null});
```

```js
$('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
    keepOpen: true,
    inline: true,
    debug: true,
    icons:{
        date: 'fa fa-calendar',
        up: 'fa fa-chevron-up',
        down: 'fa fa-chevron-down',
        previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
        next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
        today: 'fa fa-screenshot',
        clear: 'fa fa-trash',
        close: 'fa fa-remove'
    }
    //beforeShowDay:
    // daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6]
});
$('#datepicker').data("DateTimePicker").keyBinds({'enter': null});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input id="datepicker" type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @gaetonoM you say to use the keyBinds but when I try to do that and override the 'delete' key press option it does update it but also REMOVES ALL of the other default keybind options which I want to keep. How do I only remove a single keyBind option? keyBinds: {'delete': null } is what I have tried.

Comment: We want to be able to use the delete key for editing of the datetime in the field but currently the default operations is that it will clear the form field upon pressing the delete key. The field also has default functionality where the arrow keys will open up the calendar and allow the user to select a date. The issue is using the options to tell the dateTimePicker to not delete via keyBinds: {'delete': null } then we can edit the field but all other default operations stop working (e.g. arrow keys)

Comment: @gaetonoM  see above comment.

Comment: @Elijah  This is totally different from the answer here. You can see in the snippet the datepicker is always open.  What you are asking is a different question. Hence, I would suggest to ask this question and in a short you will receive an answer. **{'delete': null }** has nothing to do with **{'enter': null}**.  I hope my comment is enough clear. Thanks